# How to find quadruples in a string?

Tags: java

I have this test challenge but I'm absolutely beginner so I stuck with it, any proper solution would be really appreciated!

We'll say that a "quadruple" in a string is a char appearing four times in a row. Print the number of quadruples in the given string. The quadruples may overlap.

HINT: Watch out for spaces!

Input Format
A single line with a string.

Output Format
A number.

Sample input
abcXXXXXabc

Sample output
2

```
import java.util.*;

public class Quadruples{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = sc.nextLine();
        char [] c = s.toCharArray();
        int j=0; int k=1; int m=j+2;

        for(int i=0; i<c.length-1; i++){
            if(c[j] != c[k]){
                j++; k++;
            }else{
                for(int l=0; l<c.length-1; l++){
                    if(c[j] == c[m]){
                        m++;
                    }else{   
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Attila, welcome to SO. Please have a look at following link on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you tried so far and on which part exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Hi, I can provide a bit of code I wrote but it's definitely the right "way" to manage this problem. I started coding just a week before, I should see a working code to understand the logic.

Comment: What I tried to do is to find the first duplicated character than compare the characters afterwards to see if it's repeated 4 or more times or not. For an experienced person probably it's easy but I can't find the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple brute force approach using a for loop:

```
    String input = "abcXXXXXabc";

    // Counter to store the number of quadruples found
    int quadrupleCounter = 0;

    // Loop over each character in the input string (skip the last 3 to prevent going out of bounds)
    for(int i = 0;i < input.length() - 3; i++) {
      // Get the current char in the string + the next 3
      char c1 = input.charAt(i);
      char c2 = input.charAt(i + 1);
      char c3 = input.charAt(i + 2);
      char c4 = input.charAt(i + 3);

      // Check if all 4 characters are equal
      if(c1 == c2 && c2 == c3 && c3 == c4) {
        quadrupleCounter++; // Increase the counter
      }
    }

    System.out.println(quadrupleCounter);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I need. This code is tipically more simple than I expected. It's gonna be useful for future reference. Thanks again, I'm grateful.

Comment: By your code I can finish my one, I realised what was the problem, why did I get always outofbounds error message. Thx once more.

Answer (score 2):

Or with a regexp (just for fun):

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.)\\1{3}");
    int quadrupleCounter = 0;
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        do {
            quadrupleCounter++
        } while (matcher.find(matcher.start()+1));
    }
```

Comment: Hey, this is really cool, I really like it. I gonna study this method, it seems really useful. Thx so much.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but I think you can test it and correct it, from now on.

```
public class CheckQuadruple {
    private Boolean checkQuadrupleInString(String str, int i) {
        if (i + 3 >= str.length())
            return false;
       if (str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(i + 1))
           return false;
       if (str.charAt(i + 1) != str.charAt(i + 2))
          return false;
        if (str.charAt(i + 2) != str.charAt(i + 3))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public int findQuadruple(String str) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (checkQuadrupleInString(str, i))
                sum += 1;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I do really appreciate it.

Comment: Can you flag it as the solution? Thanks :)

Comment: `Boolean` can be `boolean`

Comment: I changed the code, now it's in a class, you just need to instante it a new object like, `CheckQuadruple c = new CheckQuadruple();` and then call the method `c.findQuadruple("TextToCheck");`

Comment: Thank you again, I'm gonna have a look on it.

Answer (score 1):

So if i undestand it correctly "aaaabcccccc" means that there are 4 quadruples in this strings for example, as you said they can overlap. so that means aaaa is 1, the first four cccc is 2, and then counting from the second c there is another one so thats 3, and then another one counting from the third c so thats 4. 
If that is so then the following code should be okay.

So we make a String 'stringArray' by splitting the string into characters. Then we use the firs for loop(with i), to iterate through all letters, then within that for loop we make another for loop to check if the current letter is equal to the next 3 letters--->if that is true, then we increment the quadCount(how many quadruples we found). Then when the forloop is done, we print out the quadCount.

You see that we check if j=i+3 is smaller then the length of the String array(in the second forloop), beacuse if there are not 3 more characters till the end of the letterArray after the one that we are checking, then surely there wont be 3 more similar ones aswell.

If watch out for the spaces means that "cc cc" does not have any quadruples in there, then the code below is correct. If that means that you should not consider spaces, and "cc cc" has one quadruples then just call the .trim() method on the String first 
like so:String quad= "aaaabccc ccc".trim();-->this will delete(trim) all spaces from the String and then the code is good.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String quad= "aaaabcccccc";
    int quadCount=0;
    String[] stringArray= quad.split("");

    for(int i=0; i<stringArray.length;i++){
        String current= stringArray[i];
        int j=i+3;
        if(j<stringArray.length){

            if(current.equals(stringArray[i+1]) && current.equals(stringArray[i+2]) && current.equals(stringArray[i+3]) ){
                quadCount++;
            }
        }

    }
        System.out.println("Quadcounter final is: "+quadCount);
    }
```

Comment: This is another good solution, thx for the detailed explanation, I can use this on another tasks as well. Nice job, thx again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop with String substring() method:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = input.nextLine();
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length()-3; i++)
        if (str.substring(i, i+2).equals(str.substring(i+2, i+4))) count++;

    System.out.print(count);
```